# Vercel Deploy Django Raised Sqlite3 Version Exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, sqlite, vercel

I am deploying Django to Vercel. But it raised the error below during running.

```
django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: deterministic=True requires SQLite 3.8.3 or higher
```

How to upgrade the Sqlite3 into 3.8.3 on Vercel server?